# Scraping data from html table, selecting elements between titles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from the following url:http://www.mobygames.com/game/xbox360/wheelman/credits with this code;

```
# Imports
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
credit_link = "http://www.mobygames.com/game/xbox360/wheelman/credits"
response = requests.get(credit_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
credit_infor= soup.find("div", class_="col-md-8 col-lg-8")
credit_infor1 = credit_infor.select('table[summary="List of Credits"]')[0].find_all('tr')
```

This is the format that I need to get:

```
info          credit_to  studio                   game       console
starring      138920     starring                 Wheelman   Xbox 360
Studio Heads  151851     Midway Newcastle Studio  Wheelman   Xbox 360
Studio Heads  73709      Midway Newcastle Studio  Wheelman   Xbox 360
```

Where info corresponds to first "td" in each row, credit_to corresponds to id of particular contributor (e.g. 138920 is id of Vin Diesel)  starring corresponds to titles. I think I can handle everything except getting studio name (i.e. titles) near each row (it will be switched from Midway Newcastle Studio to San Diego QA Team later and so on). How could I do it?

Comment: You can find the studio names by pulling the contents of the headers <h2></h2>. Just make sure you ignore the Credits header and the Starring header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your program, `credit_infor1` will have a list of all `tr` tags (rows). If you check the HTML, the rows that have the title (studio) in them, they don't have a `class` attribute. For all the other rows, they have `class="crln"` attribute.

So, you can iterate over all the rows and check if the current row has `class` as an attribute using the [**`has_attr()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) function (which is somewhat hidden in the docs). If the attribute is not present, change the title, else continue with the scraping of other data.

Continuing your program:

```
studio = ''
for row in credit_infor1:
    if not row.has_attr('class'):
        studio = row.h2.text
        continue

    # get other values that you want from this row below

    info = row.find('td').text
    # similarly get all the other values you need each time

    print(info + ' | ' + studio)
```

Partial output:

```
Starring | Starring
Studio Heads | Midway Newcastle Studio
Executive Producers | Midway Newcastle Studio
Technical Directors | Midway Newcastle Studio
Lead Programmers | Midway Newcastle Studio
...
QA Manager | San Diego QA Team
Compliance QA Manager | San Diego QA Team
QA Data Analyst | San Diego QA Team
...
SQA Analyst | SQS India QA
QA Team | SQS India QA
Executive Producers | Tigon Studios
Head of Game Production | Tigon Studios
...
```

Comment: But how can I add it as an additional row, for instance it will switch to "San Diego QA Team" later on for QA Manager -- Adam Jones

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get your problem. But, the title will change for all the titles that come in order.

Comment: As per your output requirements, if you scrape **and print** the data after the `if` block, you'll get exactly that. If you want, I can add some code to show an example.

Comment: For instance, Studio Heads Craig Duncan, Shaun Himmerick belongs to, Midway Newcastle Studio but later on studio changes "San Diego QA Team", I need to say something like while studio is "Midway Newcastle Studio" write it to studio column, then switch it to the next one

Comment: Ah, got it. You don't need to switch columns, just print all the columns for each row and change the values whenever needed. I'm adding an example...